# How to force the vmware workstation 12.5.5 to use the nvidia graphics card with optirun / primusrun? No GPU passthrough involved

Tags: debian, vmware, optimus

I am happy owner of hybrid-graphics system (sarcasm).

At my disposal I have a Nvidia GeForce GTX 960m graphics card with Intel integrated graphics card. The `lspci` names this Intel card as `Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller`. But I believe it would be enough to give the name of the processor ([Intel Core i7-4720HQ](https://ark.intel.com/products/78934/Intel-Core-i7-4720HQ-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_60-GHz)) to identify the Intel graphics card.

Yesterday I have installed VMware Workstation 12.5.5 in order to setup Windows 10 as a quest on my Debian 9 (RC3) host system. Unfortunately I have realized that my virtual machine is using Intel card instead of Nvidia card.

Let my show output of `sudo optirun nvidia-smi`:

```
Mon May 15 09:14:40 2017       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 375.39                 Driver Version: 375.39                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 960M    Off  | 0000:01:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   46C    P0    N/A /  N/A |      5MiB /  4044MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      8844    G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                               4MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

This output was collected while the VM was running 3DMark 2.3.3. Virtual machine was started as: `optirun vmware`

I know that some of you might say "*you can **not** use Nvidia card on your guest virtual machine*". But my question is **not** about GPU passthrough...

If I had to PCI passtrough my Nvidia card to the virtual machine, I would use qemu/kvm - not VMware Workstation.

All I want to do or see is the following:

1. Run `optirun vmware`
2. See VMware VM (or `vmx`) listed as a process running on the Nvidia GPU (`nvidia-smi` would be the indicator). (Sorry, by VMware VM or `vmx` I mean my guest virtual machine)

How can I force this behavior? I admit that I tried only to run `workstation` through `optirun`  but I don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By chance I found this [script](https://github.com/docsmooth/vmware-bumblebee/tree/vmware12). It comes with this [instruction](http://www.totalnetsolutions.net/2012/12/08/bumblebee-primus-and-vmware-workstation-nvidia-optimus-graphics-on-ubuntu/).

Unfortunately it does not support debian 9 (rc3), and i think that author just gave up on this project. I am not experienced enough to modify this script by myself, but with a bit of luck, someone will.

If anyone will find out how this script forces the vmware vm's to run on Nvidia card (*through `primusrun` / `optirun`*), please post an answer in this topic.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a old thread, but I'm happy owner of a bumblebee system too ***(sarcams intensifies)***, but theres the solution, because someone for sure still will need fix that insue (thanks to Vmware for do not still fix that in 2023):

1. Use the latest Nvidia driver available (nvidia-driver or nvidia-legacy-driver)
2. make sure bumblebee its working (install bumblebee-nvidia, and check for `/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia` to enable BusID based on the hardware address gave by "`$ lspci | grep VGA`" if needed)
3. Also keep in mind that Vmware **DO NOT WORK using PRIMUSRUN** so we need the old VirtualGL aproach, to enable that, make sure you edit the:

   `~/.vmware/preferences` file and add the following option:

   `mks.gl.allowBlacklistedDrivers = TRUE`

   to avoid any problem with Nvidia drivers or bumblebee being blacklisted by Vmware.
4. After setup everything use the commands:

   `$ optirun vmware &` or `$ optirun vmplayer &` based in the vmware solution you are using.

To verify if vmware its running in Nvidia card use nvidia-smi, because the output of optirun  sometimes lie.

`$ nvidia-smi`

The output should be:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 525.89.02    Driver Version: 525.89.02    CUDA Version: 12.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  On   | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   67C    P0    24W /  60W |    220MiB /  6144MiB |     32%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A     48987      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  6MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     49784    C+G   ...lib/vmware/bin/mksSandbox      211MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Where `...lib/vmware/bin/mksSandbox` its the vmware process running on Nvidia.